# Proving that an (anti) symmetric holomorphic function has no zeros in the upper half plane

Tags: complex-analysis

I am given the following information:

Suppose $f(z)$ is is analytic in the closed upper half plane satisfying $f(-z) = f^*(z^*)$. Also suppose that $\mathrm{Im}(f) \geq 0$ for real, positive $z$. We also are given the following relations that hold for real $z$:

$\mathrm{Re}(f(z) - 1) = O\left(\frac{1}{z^2}\right)$ and $\mathrm{Im}(f(z)) = O\left(\frac{1}{z^3}\right)$.

Assuming that $\mathrm{Im}(f)$ vanishes for finite real $z$ only at $z=0$, I must prove that $f(z)$ has no zeros in the upper-half plane.

I've tried numerous approaches to this but can't seem to get anywhere. Firstly, it's not hard to prove that on the positive imaginary axis, $f(z)$ must be real since if $z$ is positive imaginary, then $z^* = -z$ and $\mathrm{Im}(f(-z)) = \mathrm{Im}(f^*(z^*)) = \mathrm{Im}(-f(-z))$, so the imaginary part vanishes on the imaginary axis.

I believe this function also satisfies the requirements for the Schwartz reflection principle, which means it can be extended to $\mathbb{C}$ by the formula $f^*(z) = f(z^*)$. Using the first relation we are given, this would imply that $f(-z) = f^*(z^*) = f(z)$. How can I proceed?

Comment: What is the relation between $z$ and $\omega$ in $\mathrm{Re}(f(z) - 1) = O\left(\frac{1}{\omega^2}\right)$ ? And what limit is considered there?

Comment: Sorry, that's a typo, it should be $z$, not $\omega$.

Comment: The extension is not correct as for real $z$ we have $\Im f(z)=-\Im f(-z)$ so $f(z)$ cannot be $f(-z)$ as $f$ is real there only at $0$;